# socket.io: Emit button's attribute value on click?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I have multiple buttons with an attribute called `groupName`. They look like this:

```
<a href="#" class="fireGroup btn btn-info btn-lg" groupName="SCENE_I">SCENE I</a>
<a href="#" class="fireGroup btn btn-info btn-lg" groupName="SCENE_II">SCENE II</a>
<a href="#" class="fireGroup btn btn-info btn-lg" groupName="SCENE_III">SCENE III</a>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to get socket.io to emit the link's groupName value when clicked. So when the first link is clicked, socket.io would emit "groupName - SCENE_I"

How could this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want something similar to a chat -- where a click on a link acts as a user sending a message to the server, and the server would emit that to a room (to other users, I suppose?)

If that's the case, you should take a look at this example: http://socket.io/get-started/chat/

You would do something like this on the client side:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" class="fireGroup btn btn-info btn-lg" groupName="SCENE_I">SCENE I</a>
<a href="#" class="fireGroup btn btn-info btn-lg" groupName="SCENE_II">SCENE II</a>
<a href="#" class="fireGroup btn btn-info btn-lg" groupName="SCENE_III">SCENE III</a>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var socket = io();
  // listen to server events related to messages coming from other users. Call this event "newClick"
  socket.on('newClick', function(msg){
    console.log("got new click: " + msg);
  });

  // when clicked, do some action
  $('.fireGroup').on('click', function(){
    var linkClicked = 'groupName - ' + $(this).attr('groupName');
    console.log(linkClicked);
    // emit from client to server
    socket.emit('linkClicked', linkClicked);
    return false;
  });

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

On the server side, still taking the chat idea into consideration:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);



app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('./index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  // when linkClicked received from client... 
  socket.on('linkClicked', function(msg){
    console.log("msg: " + msg);
    // broadcast to all other users -- originating client does not receive this message.
    // to see it, open another browser window
   socket.broadcast.emit('newClick', 'Someone clicked ' + msg) // attention: this is a general broadcas -- check how to emit to a room
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Comment: Gave this a try, and it's throwing an error: `this.attr is not a function`

Comment: I changed it to `$(this).attr('groupName')` and it the error went away, it just isn't emitting anything.

Comment: I have updated the answer with more code. Also, the original `socket.broadcast.emit('Someone clicked ' + msg)` was missing the event name (added `'newClick'`). Added also a listener on client side to receive the broadcasted messages.